# Create a TXT if software exist

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a batch script to create a text file if a software exists
For example I have this broken code

```
 IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe"
```

Create a text file here C:\Users\office2016.txt with the text "Office 2016 Install Complete"

Otherwise end the script

I'm able to create a text file with this command
`@echo office 2016 installed> c:\Users\office2016.txt`

I need help combining the two together.

Comment: It is a permissions problem.  You do not have writes to create a file in C:\Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/); what you really want is some indication that Office is installed on your system.

The command `C:\Temp>if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Outlook.exe" echo Office installed >> C:\Temp\indicator.txt` works fine for me so my guess is that since you're trying to write to `C:\Users` as a non-Administrator you don't have permission to do so.

On my system when I run as non-admin:

```
C:\Users>type con > test.txt
Access is denied.

C:\Users>
```

To find out if the user has Office installed you *should* be checking the registry; the `REG` command can do that for you:

```
@echo off
REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO Office 2016 installed >> C:\Users\MyUsername\File.txt
```

Comment: I love the script however, we pushed Skype for business a few months ago without the entire office which is part of HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0  That's why I wanted to use Outlook.exe unless there is a registry key for Outlook 2016 I can use instead to know for sure.

Comment: @Sam `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook`?

Comment: Now I'm wondering if 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook' gets created even if Outlook isn't installed because as I said we pushed the office package but excluded word, excel powerpoint. I'll take a look at the machine and see if it doesn't exist if not them I'm golden. Thank you